# Wrapping primeng components? (Angular)

Tags: forms, angular, primeng

I have been using primeng for a while and now I found that I have a lot SelectButtons with the exactly same configuration in a few forms. What would be the best option for creating a general component?

I started by create a component, passing in the formControl as an input, and also the model. But... This doesn't seem the best way. (I can't put ngModel, name...).

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to do it using fordwardRef and NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR.

Comment: Did you find a way to handle both ngModel and FormControl in the same wrapper ?